# how can we calculate that in one sec how many times setInterval() function get call

Tags: jquery

I am learning HTML 5 game programming. I encounter a code that

```
var pingpong = {};
pingpong.pressedKeys = [];

$(function(){

    pingpong.timer = setInterval(gameloop,30);

    function gameloop() {
        movePaddles();

    } //end of gameloop()

}); //end of $(fn)
```

Then author says that

```
We have a timer to execute some game-related code every 30 milliseconds, so this 
code is executed 33.3 times per second.
```

I want to ask that how it is 33.3 times per second? How can we calculate it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second is 1000 milliseconds, and `setInterval(gameloop, 30)` makes sure the code runs every 30 milliseconds, thus, `1000 / 30 = 33.3`.

Comment: can you clear my confusion. see 1000 miliseconds = 1 sec; 1 millisecond = 1/1000 sec and 30 milliseconds = 1/1000 * 30 sec. gives you 30 milliseconds = 0.03 seconds. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: No, you are correct. So, the timer fires every 0.03 seconds. And how many 0.03 seconds are there in a second? 33.3. Hence, it runs 33.3 times per second.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by `how many 0.03 seconds are there in a second`. We are already in seconds....

Comment: Yes, but what the author says is that the function is executed 33.3 times in a second, i.e., one execution per 0.03 seconds.

Comment: i am confused how do you make the `1000 / 30` by the seconds and milliseconds units.

Comment: 1000 and 30 are both in milliseconds, but you can get the same result using seconds, that is, `1 second / 0.03 seconds = 33.3`.

Comment: hhmm you means after getting 0.03 seconds , to calculate that `how many 0.03 seconds are there in a second` we divide it by 1 like `1 / 0.03`. Is it ?

Comment: Yes, indeed `1 s / 0.03 s`, which is the same as `1000 ms / 30 ms`.

Answer (score 1):

**1 second** is **1000 milliseconds**.

So if the code runs every **30 milliseconds** the code is executed 1000/30 = **33.3** times per second.